# Remove "select" LinkButtons from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the rows highlighted when a row is selected, but how do I remove the column that says "select" all the way down?

Comment: How would the user select the row without the select button in the select column?

Comment: @Mithrandir Good question, I'm thinking maybe he wants to turn off the select column AFTER the user selects a row, so they can't select another one?

Comment: @Mithrandir Or he may want data column to serve as Select column

Answer (score 3):

If you have this in the `<columns>` collection of your `Gridview` markup, you need to remove it:

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
```

If you have this in your `GridView` markup (the declaration of the `GridView` itself), you need to remove it:

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
```

Or, if you want to remove it in code-behind in response to something, you can do this:

```
GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Where `columnIndex` is an `int` that represents the index of the column where the "Select" `LinkButton`s are.

If you would like to provide more details in your question, I'd be glad to be more specific =)

Answer (score 1):

After you remove the Select column as suggested by `jadarnel27` You can still allow users to select rows. 

 Use one of your other data columns as select column. I'm making the ID column a link column. Add this field and replace the ID with your dataItem

```
  <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ButtonType="Link" CommandName="Select" />
```